Not able to install AppImage in ubntu
I create .AppImage file in Ubuntu. I'm trying to install the .AppImage file in Ubuntu but I can't.
I don't know how I applied it in various ways like creating a .desktop file and setting the configuration according to the application, moving to the .local/share/application folder, setting the chmod +x permission, .AppImage file move to the /bins/ folder. Still, when I double click on the file at that time file was run but in the application list or Ubuntu search bar, appplication is not found.
So, Give me the solution on how to install the .AppImage file in Ubuntu.
Thank You!

APK is an Android Package File. So what do you mean - are you talking about AppImages or APK files? You can't do both in the same file.

I'm talking about the .AppImage extension.

Then please edit your question, and remove all references to APK files, which have nothing to do with AppImages. Thanks.

I did my changes.

If your .desktop file does not appear in your menu, then check the following:
The very minimum you need to have a working .desktop launcher is:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Name of the application
Exec=name-of-executable
Type=Application


Name is how you want to see the application labeled in the application menu/overview, and is also how you search the application. This can be anything you like.

Exec points to the executable file that is run to start the program. This can be the filename only if that file exists in one of the folders listed in the PATH  environmental variable. (Use the command printenv PATH to see these folders). Otherwise, it can be a full pathname of the executable (e.g. /opt/zotero/zotero). Make sure the Exec= line points to a valid executable:

a file that effectively exists on the file system,
a file that is executable, i.e., has the executable bit set.
is either existing in a directory that is included in the PATH environmental variable, or specified through a correct full path name.


The last line indicates this is a program launcher.


If the above minimal conditions are met, the .desktop launcher will appear in your menu.

Yes, I applied this way but it is not working, also I did the .desktop file but this way is also not working. .AppImage file will open on double click but not show into the application list in ubuntu.

This is how it works. There is no way for us to see whether you may have made some different mistake. A typo in the Exec=line is sufficient not to have it work.

I applied these steps which are given in the link: https://dev.to/tqbit/how-to-register-an-appimage-as-a-desktop-application-in-linux-31c7

I know. This is how it works. However, you may have made a mistake somewhere. Impossible to tell which from here.

I don't know where I made a mistake but can you please provide full details of .desktop file to me, which I need to set according to my .AppImage file. The file name is Autoupdater app-1.0.0.AppImage, Extension is.AppImage

I provided full detail of a minimal functional .Appimage. I think it should be the other way round: you showing your .desktop launcher so we may be able to see whether something is not right.

Since double  clicking the appimage works, you just need to create a .desktop file.
Create the file application-name.desktop with the following contents
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/path/to/your/appimage
Name=name of the software
Icon=/path/to/your/favorite/icon

Then, save the application-name.desktop file in $HOME/.local/share/applications (it is applications, not application), and mark it as executable with
chmod +x $HOME/.local/share/applications/application-name.desktop


Yes, I did the .desktop file or set the permission as well you said but when I execute the .AppImage , file is open but not installed while opening or setting the .desktop file. also, I used the desktop-application-database command to update the Application directory which is under ~/.local/share/applications.

The app menu cannot see appimages. It only sees desktop files. Did you try rebooting the computer after creating the desktop file? Did the desktop file's icon change to your preferred icon? Does the app open when you double click the desktop file?

Yes, I reboot my system after setting the .desktop file.
I applied these steps which are given in the link: https://dev.to/tqbit/how-to-register-an-appimage-as-a-desktop-application-in-linux-31c7
